# How to delete orphaned list visible in content database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have document library in a team site that needs to be deleted. For some reason it is not visible in the site, nor it is there in the recycle bin. I am sure that is not hidden in any way.

I looked into the content db, and found that the list is present in the AllLists table. I got the GUID of the list and tried to delete it using the below command

```
PS C:\Users\spadmin> Get-SPWeb "http://teamsites/sites/siteA/subSiteA" | Where-Object {$_.Lists.Delete([System.Guid]"F341C105-7C2F-4F60-97EC-5B232C4FC94E")}
```

And I am seeing the following error.

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "1" argument(s): "List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."
At line:1 char:86
+ Get-SPWeb "http://teamsites/sites/siteA/subSiteA" | Where-Object {$_.Lists.Delete <<<< ([System.Guid]"F341C105-7C2F-4F60-97EC-5B232C4FC94E")}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any idea how to get rid of this list. I want to delete it completely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if the list does not appear in the ui, explorer view, or through available apis, you shouldn't be concerned, as the content database works in mysterious ways

additionally, you can check the end user recycle bin and the admin recycle bin

Comment: Thanks Tiago for your reply. I have checked the user recycle bin and admin recycle bin. But the list is not there.

Comment: why are you trying so bad to find it?

Comment: just want to remove any kind to of references to that list or any item in it.

Comment: I understand. but editing (event looking) into the content database is not supported by microsoft. whatever is there is their business. you are just supposed to use OOTB features and existing APIs. if you have removed it you should consider it gone, otherwise you can create a new content database for your site, should that be an option (dev, test sites). sometimes, deleted stuff is kept for some days (recycled items) or indefinitely (get-spdeletedsite), and for those you can take a look, but never inside the database itself

Comment: Yes I was just checking the content db. Didn't change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some tool like SharePoint Manager to check the document library. There can be lists in SharePoint that are "hidden". These lists are typically created by complex features and are used internally for their functions. So it may be not a good idea to delete them.